# OpenACC on Intel built-in graphics cards (Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655)

Tags: intel, gpgpu, openacc

I would like to find out, whether built-in Intel graphics cards (e.g. Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655) support OpenACC directives? Would anyone be able to direct me to any relevant information?

Answer (score 1):

The [PGI C compiler](https://www.pgroup.com/products/community.htm) does not support Intel as a target architecture, where architecture can be specified with the `-ta` option:

```
pgcc -I../common -acc -ta=nvidia,time -Minfo=accel -o laplace2d_acc laplace2d.c
```

Compiler issues the following warning:

```
pgcc-Warning-OpenACC for GPUs no longer supported on macOS, enabling multicore CPU code generation. Use -ta=multicore to avoid this warning
```

That means that no GPUs are supported on macOS, but it is still possible to compile the code with OpenACC directives aiming for execution on multiple cores of the CPU with `-ta=multicore`:

```
pgcc -I../common -acc -ta=multicore,time -Minfo=accel -o laplace2d_acc laplace2d.c
```

[GNU C compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/OpenACC#Quick_Reference_Guide) (starting from version 7) supports OpenACC (ver. 7 and 8 support OpenACC 2.0a, ver. 9--OpenACC 2.5), where the `acc` directives are enabled with the `-fopenacc` option:

```
gcc -I../common -fopenacc -o laplace2d_acc laplace2d.c
```

However, I wasn't able to find compiler flags to target the Intel Iris card specifically.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there are no OpenACC compilers supporting the Intel GPUs. As you've discovered, PGI and GNU both currently do not. I don't believe the CLACC effort is far enough along to test whether it's capable. The Intel compiler does not support OpenACC. IIRC the PathScale compiler did not support Intel before they went out of business.